# Gerrit reject change in GUI

Tags: git, version-control, gerrit

How does one configure access in the Gerrit UI to allow check ins to be rejected?  I know the general rule of thumb is if a piece of code has a certain score it should be ignored, but is there a clean way to reject a branch outright?  I ask because I just had to go through an awful merge/approve/rebase cycle in Gerrit.

Use of the abandon button, did not remove the "rejected" change from the dependency tree.

Answer (score 1):

If something is completely wrong, it is typically abandoned through the 'Abandon' button in the web UI.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: So even when using the abandon button it still creates the issue of having a dependency on that abandoned change.  How do we resolve that?

Comment: True - if you have pushed up other commits for review which have the (now abandoned) change in their history, they will depend on the abandoned commit in the UI.  The solution is to use 'git rebase' to modify the commit tree so that the abandoned commit is no longer present.

Comment: Is that git rebase from eclipse (egit) or git rebase from elsewhere?

Comment: I prefer to use git rebase form the command line - see http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing - but yes egit should work fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up some continuous integration magic that will automatically do things like run lint checkers, run unit tests, etc, and then have the results of those things trigger different behaviors in gerrit. At the Wikimedia Foundation, we use something like this to automatically flag bad commits - we don't outright reject them, but potentially use this to give a low score to prevent merging until a real person has the chance to look at the commit. We use Jenkins to handle all of the automatic job runs. Some quick googling for ['gerrit and jenkins'](https://www.google.com/search?q=gerrit+and+jenkins&oq=gerrit+and+jenkins&aqs=chrome.0.57j65l2j60l2j62.1668&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) reveals all kinds of guides on how to set something like this up.